# Delete all files and subdirectories but keep the current directory empty in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a folder "/a/b/" and I would like to delete everything inside of folder b, including files, directories and files and subdirectories inside of these directories, but I want to keep folder b empty without delete it. What I have tried was:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/a/b/"))//
                 .map(Path::toFile)//
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::isDirectory))//
                 .forEach(File::delete);
```

this solution worked fine when it deleted everything inside of folder b, but it deleted also folder b which I would like to keep. How should I change here to keep folder b, can anyone give me a tip? Thank you

Comment: Nice question btw ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter all but this directory :

```
Path rootPath = Paths.get("/a/b/");
Files.walk(rootPath)//
     .filter(p -> !p.equals(rootPath))
     .map(Path::toFile)//
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::isDirectory))//
     .forEach(File::delete);
```

---

Note that  `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::isDirectory))` may not be enough.
Deleting the directories in first instance matters but their deletion order matters too.

Suppose you have directories :  `/a/b/`, `/a/b/c`, `/a/b/c/d`.
You want to delete directory depth-last before depth-first, that is  `/a/b/c/d` before  `/a/b/c`.
But `File.walk()` walks depth-first. So it will iterate in the order : `/a/b/`,  `/a/b/c`, `/a/b/c/d`.
So reverse the natural order of the stream of `File` :

```
 .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Comment: My idea was to simply recreate it afterwards, but this one is obviously way cooler!

Comment: @GhostCat Hey. With Exception handling, it is less cool :'( But thanks :)

Comment: @GhostCat `Path.equals()` is overriden. So finally cool again

Comment: Be aware that, Files.walk() does not close the resources opened. 
you should use with

try(Files.walk( ....)) {
}

Comment: @Brother `Stream.forEach()` closes the stream. So the resources of `DirectoryStreams` are de facto released.

Comment: @davidxxx No, it is not (unfortunately), I just found a couple of months ago. Look in my answer updated with this part. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111012/3154883

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileUtils from apache commons-io:

```
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(Paths.get("/a/b/").toFile());
```

Docs: [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory(java.io.File))

UPDATED: Only for knowledge, according to documentation for **File.walks**:

```
The returned stream encapsulates one or more {@link DirectoryStream}s.
 * If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the
 * {@code try}-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the
 * stream's {@link Stream#close close} method is invoked after the stream
 * operations are completed.
```

So, unless you use like this:

```
try(Stream<Path> paths = Files.walks(...)) {
  //Operations here with paths
}
```

The stream will no close, even with forEach.